# « [...] sur un dollar d'impôt sur le revenu, seulement quatre centimes proviennent de la taxation de la richesse » ?

Tags: sens, nombres, synonymes, unités, finance

> Elle [ l'ONG *[Oxfam International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxfam#Oxfam_International)* ] a ainsi précisé que sur un
>   dollar d'impôt sur le revenu, seulement quatre **centimes** proviennent
>   de la taxation de la richesse.
>
> Selon Oxfam, qui estime que les plus riches cachent au fisc 7600
>   milliards de dollars, dans certains pays comme le Brésil ou le
>   Royaume-Uni « les 10 % les plus pauvres paient désormais des impôts
>   plus élevés en proportion de leurs revenus que les plus riches ».
>
> [ [*Les 26 plus riches détiennent autant d'argent que la moitié de
>   l'humanité*](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/economie/international/201901/20/01-5211734-les-26-plus-riches-detiennent-autant-dargent-que-la-moitie-de-lhumanite.php), La Presse via l'AFP ]

L'article dresse un constat révoltant (voir [communiqué](https://www.oxfam.org/fr/salle-de-presse/communiques/2019-01-18/lannee-derniere-la-fortune-des-milliardaires-augmente-tous) d'*Oxfam*). J'ai noté un sens de [*centime*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/centime) en finance (*Centimes additionnels. Centime le franc*) soit le « taux d'imposition de la valeur imposable de biens fonciers » (TLFi). Ça ne cadre pas avec le propos, il me semble, où de surcroît on réfère au dollar...

---

*Centime* est-il synonyme de [*pourcent*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pourcent) ; de [*centième*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/centi%C3%A8me) ; dois-je faire un calcul avec pour base une devise antérieure à l'*euro* ?

Comment: Pourquoi je ne peux mettre deux points d'interrogation au titre pour illustrer ma perplexité ??

Comment: Voilà l'explication : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115352/182055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Centime* est utilisé ici comme synonyme de *cent* (donc centième de dollar), par extension du sens de centime d'euro.

Avant l'arrivée de l'Euro, *centime* était réservé aux monnaies libellées en francs (ainsi qu'en dirhams marocains et dinars algériens), mais depuis le passage à l'euro en 2001, c'est aussi devenu le synonyme [recommandé](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/centime) de *cent* en Français. Le TLFi n'étant plus mis à jour depuis 1994, ne connait donc ni cet usage, ni l'euro (nom choisi en 1995), ni même son prédécesseur l'ECU, crée en en 1976.

Bien qu'Euro *cent* soit l'unité indiquée sur les pièces, ce nom est difficile à utiliser en raison de son homonymie avec le nombre *cent*. Les solutions choisies par le français canadien sont *cenne* qui est inconnu en France, et *sou* qui est difficilement acceptable, un *sou* valant historiquement cinq centimes.